# Cannot click input element within button element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

Take a look at the below markup & fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/minlare/oh1mg7j6/

```
<button id="button" type="button">
    <span id="test" style="background:pink;">test element</span>
    Add File
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" id="upload">
</button>
```

In Chrome, each element within the button can be selected through the developer console and js click events are delegated.

In Firefox/IE you cannot select the child elements or pickup js click events.

Is there a way around this in Firefox/IE?

Comment: That's not valid HTML markup. A button cannot contains interactive content such as input element (except of type hidden). You'd have better to explain why do you need to wrap an input type file inside a button, doesn't really make sense

Comment: this is working inFirfox And Chrome as well; refer this codepen http://codepen.io/drewrygh/pen/rCucG

Comment: An older verion of http://fineuploader.com/ required a button element (for init), and it then inserted the input element @A.Wolff

Comment: @minlare Sounds strange! Any concrete example? Why don't you upgrade plugin version?

Comment: Licensing prevents upgrade, I'll opt for using a div (remember having an issue when not using a button, but cant remember what it was... hopefully I'll be okay or it'll crop up again soon!) Thanks @A.Wolff

Comment: `Licensing prevents upgrade` Ah ya, this happen sometimes :( Anyway, glad you've fixed it

Comment: @minlare Fine Uploader never required a `<button>` element for the file chooser. In fact, the FAQ has stated for quite some time *not* to use a `<button>` due to the fact that the click event will never target the child input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not suggested to use elements inside button and so you can use "div" instead of "button" which will make it working both in mozilla and chrome. Check below

```
<div id="button" type="button">
    <span id="test" style="background:pink;">test element</span>
    Add File
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" id="upload">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oh1mg7j6/8/

Comment: Thanks, this was to be my next step, just hoping there may have been a way to achieve this with css

Comment: @minlare if above solution helped, mark it as answer / vote it

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good style.Even I can say that this way is not right.you can set "click" event on your button to click the input.so if you want to hide input[file] element,but leave it clickable you can do like I said.Here is a very good link for events docs and examples.

http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/javascript-events.html